Do I need to apply for a family visa if I have a pre-settlement to remain in the UK?
I am an Algerian passport holder. I moved to the UK in May 2019 to join my wife on a 6-month family visa. Once that expired I applied for a 5-year family visa, which is due to expire in November 2024. However, in the meantime I applied for the settlement and I was given a 5-year pre-settlement in 2021. This is due to expire in 2026. I currently hold a family visa and a pre-settlement.
I have contacted gov visa and immigration and they were not able to help me, but they did make me aware that I should only have one or the other.
My question is, do I need to apply for another family visa or can I remain in the UK on my pre-settlement?
How can I apply for indefinite leave?

Have you read the guidance on Check if you can get indefinite leave to remain? Which of the qualifying categories applies to your situation?

What is the basis of your pre-settled status?  Is your wife an EU citizen who was living in the UK before the end of the transition period?

Yes my wife is an EU national and lives in the UK

You should be able to stay with pre-settled status until the pre-settled status runs out, in 2026, but you can stay until November 2024 anyway. Also since you entered the UK in May 2019, after May 2024 you can apply again for settled status and you should receive it. Because you are in the exact same situation as you were in 2021, except now you would qualify for settled (instead of presettled) status because you have been in the UK for 5 years when you apply again. So I would apply for settled status as soon as you are in the UK for five years and not wait until the family visa runs out in November.
There are rumours that because practically everybody who received pre-settled status will be entitled to settled status eventually, the authorities decided to do away with the second application because it is just unnecessary work. I wouldn't rely on that.

It is VERY important to do the 2nd application as otherwise will get the same issue as the Windrush generation with lost paperwork and unable to prove entitlement later.   Application should be automatically granted if for example paid NI in UK for previous five years as easy to assess database then proves entitled to settled status.
